# Given an array of matches, find all documents that have atleast one match and replace all matches with given value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

I am new to mongodb and im trying to (as title says) "Given an array of matches, find all documents that have atleast one match and replace all matches with given value"

For example, lets say i have those documents in my mongodb:

```html
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e90880a39cfeaaf0b97b576"),
    "StudentName": [
      "Chris, C",
      "David, O",
      "Mike, K",
      "Sam, Bard"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e90880a39cfeaaf0b97b577"),
    "StudentName": [
      "Joe, J",
      "John, K",
      "David, O",
      "Sam, Ba rd",
      "Sam, B"
    ]
  }
]
```

And i want to find all documents that contains either ["Sam, B", "Sam, Bard", "Sam, Ba rd"] and replace with "Sam"

Expected result:

```html
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e90880a39cfeaaf0b97b576"),
    "StudentName": [
      "Chris, C",
      "David, O",
      "Mike, K",
      "Sam"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e90880a39cfeaaf0b97b577"),
    "StudentName": [
      "Joe, J",
      "John, K",
      "David, O",
      "Sam",
      "Sam"
    ]
  }
]
```

What i tried to do:

```
db.collection.updateMany({ "StudentName":  {"$in":["Sam, B", "Sam, Bard", "Sam, Ba rd"]} },{ "$set": { "StudentName.$": "Sam" } })
```

Which didn't work. Any help? Thank you very much.

EDIT1: I need it to be dynamic, i'll be providing the array of possibles matches and the string to replace with through a NodeJS application.

EDIT2: To give an example for EDIT1, i could pass an array like this ["John,"Bob","Jessica","Robert"] to replace with "Josh"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this.  By the looks of it you want this to be done via one command that can be run directly in the shell.

You can do this leveraging `arrayFilters` option within `updateMany`.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#std-label-updateMany-arrayFilters for further documentation on it.

For simplicity I won't leverage indices so the below command would iterate over all the documents in the collection.  If you want to leverage an index you would just adjust the query portion of the `updateMany`

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   { },
   { $set: { "StudentName.$[element]" : "Sam" } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { "element":  /.*Sam.*/i } ] }
)
```

The above will replace any value that contains "Sam" with the value "Sam".  So "Sam I Am" would be replaced with "Sam".

If you know the values you are trying to replace:

```
db.students.updateMany(
   { },
   { $set: { "StudentName.$[element]" : "Ana" } },
   { arrayFilters: [ {  "element": { $in:  ["John", "Jessica", "Robert", "Rob"] } } ] }
)
```

which would replace all values of John, Jessica, Robert and Rob with "Ana".

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i need it to be dynamic, sorry if i didn't specify earlier. So this could be done for any StudentName. 
For example, i could try to find either ["Rob", "Rob, C", "Robert"] and replace with "Carl".
I'm doing it through a NodeJS backend that will provide the array of things to find for (Rob array above) and the string to replace with ( in the example "Carl")

Comment: @jay2p You would just replace /.*Sam.*/i with /.*Rob.*/i  and then replace "Sam" with "Carl".  So just create intermediary variables to store the respective values that could change and in your application you would change the values as needed.

Comment: I see, thank you for your reply, but in my case i don't think regex would work because in the array of matches could be anything, for example ["John", "Jessica", "Robert", "Rob"] and replace with "Ana".  I could call the updateMany query one time for each in the array but id like a way to call it only once, if possible.
I would need an exact match of the strings inside the array.

Comment: I don't quite understand the use case where this would be necessary.  @jay2p .  You can use the $in operator along with `arrayFilters` but then you would need to have the exact values you are trying to replace.  I'll edit above to show that example as well.

Otherwise you might have to do this in multiple steps or in a `forEach` loop for each document.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed! Thank you so much, you are doing gods work!

Comment: @jay2p Glad it helped!  When you get the chance if you could mark it as the answer, it would be appreciated.